# SerializerMethodField: Get field from some other Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Can we get field from some some other model model having OneToOneField relion with that field
using SerializerMethodField?

Thank you in advance fellow programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, its simple. 
Ex.

```
#Example account model which maps to user via one to one.

class Account(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User)
    ... other fields

#Example account serializer which has email field as SerializerMethodField
class AccountSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    # other serializer fields
    email = serializer.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_email(self, obj)
        return obj.user.email
```

Comment: when I do that I am getting this error  AttributeError at /song/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'

Comment: Serializermethod field is only a read only field. So you need to supply a object or a quesryset of object of model that you want to serialize. Show me the serializer that you have written and your model relationship.

Comment: This is my serializer and model I have only changed the relation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61737335/python-foreignkey-relation-with-user-shows-this-error-not-null-constraint-failed

Comment: Don't specify performer in read only tuple, then try and it doesnt work. Update this querstion with the complete stack trace of the error

Comment: @PranayAmbre hey if you are satisfied with my answer could you please upvot my answer.